# Testing whether polynomial is in algebra of other polynomials

Tags: algebra, mathematical-software

A collection $\Sigma$ of polynomials is an algebra if: (1) $\lambda f + \eta g \in \Sigma$ for any $f,g \in \Sigma, \lambda,\eta \in \mathbb{R}$ and (2) $f,g \in \Sigma$ implies $fg \in \Sigma$. We say that $P$ is in the algebra of $\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$ if $P$ is in the smallest algebra containing $P_1,\dots,P_n$.

I was wondering if there was a way, on any computer math software, to check whether a given $P$ as in the algebra of a given collection $P_1,\dots,P_n$.

**Example**: take $n \ge 1$ and let $P_1 = x_1+\dots+x_n, P_2 = x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2,\dots P_n = x_1^n+\dots+x_n^n$. Then all $n$ of the following symmetric functions are in the algebra generated by $P_1,\dots,P_n$: $$x_1+\dots+x_n$$ $$x_1x_2+\dots+x_{n-1}x_n$$ $$x_1x_2x_3+\dots+x_{n-2}x_{n-1}x_n$$ $$\dots$$ $$x_1\dots x_n$$

I'd appreciate any help.